# How to translate Google Analytics dashboard?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, dashboard, google-visualization

I'm useing [gadash library](http://analytics-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/reporting/javascript/ez-ga-dash/docs/user-documentation.html#reference) and I can't figure out how to translate chart legend labels.

In [this example demo](http://analytics-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/reporting/javascript/ez-ga-dash/demos/set-demo.html) I get "Visitors, Visits, Pageviews". I'd like those translated.

My code:

```
  <script>
    var dataOverTime = new gadash.Chart({
        'last-n-days': 30,
        'chartOptions': {
            width: 700
        },
        'divContainer': 'dataOverTimeConfig',
        'type': 'LineChart',
        'query': {
          'dimensions': 'ga:date',
          'sort': 'ga:date',
          'metrics': 'ga:visitors, ga:visits, ga:pageviews',
          'ids' : TABLE_ID    
        },
        'chartOptions': {
            height: 300,
            legend: {position: 'bottom'},
            hAxis: {title:'Data'},
            curveType: 'function'
        }
    }).render();
  </script>
```

Is there any "locale" property I could add to the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was custom onSuccess function:

```
        'onSuccess': function(resp) {              
            var dataTable = gadash.util.getDataTable(resp);
            // customized part
            dataTable.z[1].label = "First custom label";
            dataTable.z[2].label = "Second custom label";
            dataTable.z[3].label = "Third custom label";
            // end of customized part
            var chart = gadash.util.getChart(this.config.divContainer, this.config.type);
            gadash.util.draw(chart, dataTable, this.config.chartOptions);
            gadash.onSuccess();
        }
```